# Executing Javascript as soon as UpdatePanel trigger is fired

Tags: c#, javascript, updatepanel

I have found out it is possible to execute javascript *after* an UpdatePanel has updated it's contents, but is it possible to execute javascript as soon as the trigger is fired?

I could probably hack some messy javascript, but I was wondering if ASP.NET had any 'inbuilt' functionality?

Answer (score 3):

Quote from [MSDN - endRequest Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383810.aspx):

> The endRequest event is raised after an asynchronous postback is finished and control has been returned to the browser.

In other words you can attach a javascript handler function to the beginning and ending of a partial postback (when the update panel updates).

In the example on the page, you can see that the handler is attached using the `PageRequestManager`:

`Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(endRequestHandler)`

For reference purposes:

[beginRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397432.aspx) - Start of the Request.

[endRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383810.aspx) - When the request is completed.

Answer (score 0):

UpdatePanel usage implies full page life cycle to be triggered again, so you should be able to  catch the document ready, in jQuery terms, like this:

```
$(function() {
 // Handler for .ready() called.
});
```

see here: http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Comment: If i got him right, he wants to run some JS before or during the postback. Something similar to the UpdateProgress control

Answer (score 0):

I guess there are a few options here you could obviously do something like the following.

```
<div id="Container" onclick="__doPostBack('UpdatePanel1', '');">
```

But any of the page life cycle events could be used [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx) is an excellent resource on what and when everything gets called.